# How does GCP iot-device-sdk-embedded-c work on MIPS(uclibc)?

Tags: c, mips, embedded-linux, google-cloud-iot

I download source code [iot-device-sdk-embedded-c](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c) from github.
I **only** change config for tool-chain and then compiler it successfully. But it stop in connect step(iotc_connect_to), when I run example "iot_core_mqtt_client" in my device(MIPS+uclibc). This example work in google shell, x86_64 linux and ARM linux.

My Device:
CPU: MIPS
OS: Linux 3.10.14
tool-chain : CC=mips-linux-uclibc-gnu-gcc-4.7.2 AR=mips-linux-uclibc-gnu-gcc-ar

Can iot-device-sdk-embedded-c run in MIPS+uclibc? 
What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the answer....
"SOCK_STREAM" is defined to 1 for any other architectures, but it is defined to 2 for MIPS.
And then iotc_bsp_io_net_posix.c didn't use socket.h file from MIPS include folder.
That's reason why my device can't send data to server.